# Download file from Google Drive - method is missing? (java)

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I try to use the Java API of Google Drive to download all files in a certain folder. Since I am beginner with this API I googled and found several questions and answers about this here on SO, e.e.,[Download files from google drive using java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45182550/download-files-from-google-drive-using-java-api)

All these examples use the following construction:

```
if (file.getDownloadUrl() !=null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0) {
```

However, when I use this (in Eclipse) (it is of course simplified)

```
com.google.api.services.drive.model.File myFile = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
myFile.getDownloadUrl();
```

I get an error message `The method getDownloadUrl() is undefined for the type File`. Furthermore, googling for this method name does not reveal any meaningful results. Am I missing something very fundamental here?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `com.google.api.services.drive.model.File myFile = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
myFile.getDownloadUrl();` makes no sense. You are trying to assign a String (the return value of getDownloadUrl()) to a File object.

However, the compiler hasn't got round to complaining about this yet because it can't find the `downloadUrl()` method signature. My guess is that you are using the wrong jar file for the API. In this case I think you're trying to use the v2 API but have probably downloaded the v3 jar.  It is better to follow the Google documentation rather than copy/paste code from StackOverflow.

Comment: I event have same problem. I am using v3 API and i want to use getDownloadUrl() method. 
There should be another methods to get download URL.
Please tell me which method should i use?

Answer (score 1):

The method `file.getDownloadUrl()` has been removed in Drive API v3.
Try to use the method `executeMediaAndDownloadTo()` instead of using `getDownloadUrl()` in order to download google drive files. See the following [sample code](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads).

The method `executeMediaAndDownloadTo()` in the [`Drive.File.Get` class](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.Files.Get.html).